# What determines the layout of the New and Edit actions on a record?

Tags: lightning, page-layout, lightning-record-page, dynamic-forms

When I added a Field Section component (Dynamic Forms) to a lightning record page, it overrode the page layout for New and Edit actions, removing those fields (which are also on the record page as Record Detail component).

Where is Salesforce documentation for how the layout of New and Edit actions are determined and how to change them?

Comment: Since I couldn't find this behaviour documented, I thought this question would be useful. If you vote down, please comment why or suggest a change to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation here explains the behaviour of new/edit actions using page field sections, and recommends against having both field sections and record detail components: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_considerations.htm&type=5

(Rather than searching for how the new/edit action layouts are determined I searched for dynamic forms.)